# What is the correct medical procedure(s) for taking a resting heart rate?

Tags: cardiology

**Note:** I thought the Biology stack exchange would suit this question better than the Fitness stack exchange. Please let me know in the comments if this is not suitable here.

I am interested in tracking my resting heart rate as it decreases with aerobic training.

At the moment I take it immediately after I have woken up before I get up out of bed.

---

**What is the correct medical procedure(s) for taking a resting heart rate?**

I'm aware a standardized procedure is important but what about:

1. Body position: Should I be sitting or lying down?
2. Heart rate: Should I take the lowest value or an average HR?
3. What duration should I take it for?
4. How relaxed should I be?

**In an academic situation how would one reliably take resting a heart rate?**

Please include answers that can be referenced to scientific or medical literature.

Answer (score 1):

1) According to [this article](http://www.intervalsforcardio.com/resting-heart-rate.html) you should be taking it in the most preferred position you want. It would change according to the position you are in so make yourself comfortable sitting or lying down ([reference](http://btc.montana.edu/olympics/physiology/cf01.html)).

2) You take the number of beats of your heart in a minute. If you take the number of beats for 2 minutes, then average your count by 2.

3) One minute ([reference](http://exercise.about.com/od/cardioworkouts/g/restingheartrat.htm)).

4) Completely relaxed, most articles recommend taking it in the morning while waking up so you are doing the right thing ([reference](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/dennis-kravetz/heart-rate_b_4428266.html)).

I don't understand what you mean by an academic situation so I could try and answer it if you clarified it.